# python cuda, adding @autojit before class functions

Tags: python, function, class, anaconda

I can see from here: [NumbaPro Example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/harrism/f5707335f40af9463c43) that the easiest way to speed up python while working in Anaconda is to simply do the following:

```
from numba import autojit

@autojit
def myfunction(params):
    #do something
```

However, I have a slightly different case, I have a function in a class and I'm thinking that maybe that's the reason I'm getting this error:

```
    class GentleBoostC:
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gentleboost_c_class.py", line 64, in GentleBoostC
    @autojit
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\decorators.py", line 183, in autojit
    nopython=nopython, locals=locals, **kwargs)(func)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\decorators.py", line 164, in _autojit_decorator
    compilerimpl = compiler_cls(env, f, nopython, flags, template_signature)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\wrapping\compiler.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.ast = functions._get_ast(py_func)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\functions.py", line 89, in _get_ast
    ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST | flags, True)
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gentleboost_c_class.py", line 1
    def train(self, X, y, H):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

My code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.externals.six.moves import zip
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import math
from skimage import data, io, filter, color, exposure
from numba import autojit

class GentleBoostC:

    # some initializer functions

    @autojit
    def train(self, X, y, H):
            # do something
```

The error says there's something wrong with the indentation of the `@autojit` line, but there isn't. Is there a different way to use it if I'm working with classes? I tried adding the line `@autojit` before the class definition, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you check that you aren't mixing tabs and spaces in an incompatible way?  If you run with `python -tt`, It'll yell at you if you mix them :)

Comment: I'm running in Anaconda's Spyder though. Not command line... how would I use python -tt in Spyder?

Comment: Since you put CUDA in the question title, I assume you actually want NumbaPro to use your GPU.  If that's the case then you want to use `from numbapro import cuda` and `@cuda.autojit`.